# Using same Azure role project with different role names in a ccproj

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have a role project (say, called `MyRole`) in my cloud project (`.ccproj`).

So adding this `MyRole.csproj` project as a role will result an Azure role called `MyRole` while running the deployment.

I was wondering, can I reuse this `MyRole.csproj` to have another role with a different name (say, `MyRole2`) in the same cloud project?

I only need two roles with different names (`Role.Name`) with duplicating the codebase. Any ideas?

Comment: why would you want to that in a single deployment? First thing is, that you cannot use same Endpoints in both the roles. Rest is - there is something wrong with your architecture if you want 2 roles. Probably you want 2 instances of the same role? Read [this](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/12/windows-azure-basics-part-1-of-n.html) and [that](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html) articles to make difference between Role and Instance. Then refine your question if necessary.

Comment: I am not architecturing anything, I need to do an experiment. My role is neutral, I just need to get it with a different name without copy pasting the code. Remember, this is just an experiment.

Comment: Do you make [difference between Role and Instance](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/12/windows-azure-basics-part-1-of-n.html) and do you understand [the endpoint limitations](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html)? If, yes, please refine your question. Even for `experimenting`, the current state of the question shows that you have no clear idea about what is Role, what is Instance, and most importantly - the endpoint limitations.